# Bootbox does the same for "ok" and "cancel" callback. It does the same for prompt as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

Bootbox closes and stays on the same page. It should redirect to a different page onClick and "ok" after that. It is an MVC application and redirects to Index action upon Click. The same code works for traditional Jquery confirm box.

```
$('.navbar, .navv').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

if(bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to leave the page!",
    function (result) {
        if (result === true) {
            return true; //should redirect to the Home page
        } else {
            return false; //Should stay in the same page
        }
    }));
});
```

Comment: This is covered in the documentation, specifically in the [Known Limitations](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#known-limitations) section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `if` loop around `bootbox.confirm` and return only if it is `true`.

```
$('.navv').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to leave the page!",
    function (result) {        
        if(result) {
        window.open($('.navv').attr('href'));
      };
  });
});
```

Click on this link to see demo. https://jsfiddle.net/y3o8gamp/

Comment: changed the code as suggested but has the same pattern. I guess it is working in your fiddle because you are opening a window rather than passing a boolean.

Comment: @SampannaPokhrel If you don't want to redirect in new window, you can use `location.href = 'some url'` instead of `window.open` to redirect in the same window/tab.

Comment: I need to redirect it to an action in the controller. I tried using the $.ajax as well. It didn't work.

Comment: @SampannaPokhrel Can you make sure you are attaching the click event to the anchor tags only? If you are using bootstrap's navbar, I think you your current code is not attaching the click event on links inside it. I have created [a new fiddle](http://jsbin.com/gevatocete/2/edit?js,output) for it, check it out and let me know to update my answer.

Comment: I saw you used the alert after bootbox. The whole reason I am using bootbox is to give it a bit more advanced form. It works if I use traditional confirm returning the boolean. It just doesn't work if using bootbox. Once again I am sending callback as a boolean, not anchor tab or an alert(defeats the whole purpose if I use traditional js boxes). I am thankful for your comments though.

Answer (score 0):

please check result value, if was null == cancel button cliked if was empty string '' ok button with empty comment box clicked.

this worked for me.